# Generating an analog sawtooth ramp for PWM

Tags: analog, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, vco

I came across the circuit below:

[image]
*[Source](https://www.edn.com/use-a-low-cost-pwm-ramp-generator-in-switch-mode-power-supplies/)*

I can't seem to understand how the circuit works. They even say that one can set the maximum duty cycle. Kindly explain to me how the circuit works. I would also appreciate other recommendations.

Comment: Note that the basic explanation to the circuit's operation is in the article you link to. It may seem a bit tricky but the LM393 has an open collector output (it can only pull low), so R3 and C2 are significant to the timing function.

Comment: @Nedd what about setting the maximum duty cycle. That is what is giving me challenges

Comment: You might assume that maximum duty cycle (100%) in this case implies that the saw-tooth's falling edge time is close to zero. In the article the chart below the schematics give some of the variations of duty cycle and frequency (frequency = 1/period), for different component values. Also per the article R1,R2,C1 sets the off time, while R3,C2 sets the period. In more simple terms C2 mainly affects the rising ramp, and C1 mainly affects the reset to low.

Comment: @Nedd Thanks for the explanation